# Error: RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout. The relevant error-causing widget was Scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

[image]

When i am wrapping scafflod with SingleChildScrollView this error is occured, anyone can give ma a solution for this

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet instead of image

Comment: wrap your `scaffold` in a SizedBox with finite height for Example `height : 300`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make **Scaffold** parent widget and inside scaffold body use **SingleChildScrollView**

Structure
*Scaffold -> body:SingleChildScrollView -> child: Other widgets*

Answer (score 1):

`Scaffold` comes over `SingleChildScrollView`